# How can i use dataProvider in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, sql, vaadin, vaadin7

Hello all i am trying to make a grid with data in mydatabase posgresql 
Anyway i want to make a filtering are insede the grid there is a doc in vaadin [vaadin grid example filtering](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features) but i am using vaadin 7 in my code i wrote someting like that

```
private void setKolonFiltre() { 

    BeanItemContainer<AdmKullanicilar> filterContainer =  
                                         new BeanItemContainer<>(AdmKullanicilar.class);
    GeneratedPropertyContainer filterProperty = 
                                         new GeneratedPropertyContainer(filterContainer);

    filteringHeader= tblKullanici.appendHeaderRow();        

    TextField filteringField = getColumnFilterField();
    filteringField.addValueChangeListener(e ->{
        filterContainer.addContainerFilter();
    });
}
```

is there any way to use [`DataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html) in Vaadin 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use DataProvider in Vaadin 7, it has been introduced in Vaadin 8.

Here are some old examples of ContainerFilter use with Vaadin 7 (since filtering is done via Container, it works same way with Grid)

https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/trunk/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/datamodel/ContainerFilterExample.java

Comment: Thanks for answer and thnaks you for time